# refactor data.frame column values

Tags: r, dataframe

Sorry guys if this is a noob question.
I need help on how to loop over my dataframe.Here is a sample data.

```
a <- c(10:29);
b <- c(40:59);
e <- rep(1,20);
test <- data.frame(a,b,e)
```

I need to manipulate column "e" using the following criteria for values in column "a"

for all values of

"a" <= 15, "e" = 1,

"a" > 15 & < 20, "e" = 2

"a" > 20 & < 25, "e" = 3

"a" > 25 & < 30, "e" = 4 and so on to look like this

```
result <- cbind(a,b,rep(1:4, each=5))
```

My actual data frame is over 100k long. Would be great if you could sort me out here.

Comment: I think the title should reflect what's being done here. You're trying to add a recoded column based on values from other columns.

Comment: Sorry Roman about the not optimal title, you are right - its about recoding a column based on others. But you guys have sorted me out anyways :)

Comment: Just trying to help the next person interested in this problem. By giving it an informative title, there's a better chance that your answer will help someone. Feel free to edit the title to reflect your Q. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
data.frame(a, b, e=(1:4)[cut(a, c(-Inf, 15, 20, 25, 30))])
```

**Update:**

[Greg's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/430909/greg-snow) comment provides a more direct solution without the need to go via subsetting an integer vector with a factor returned from `cut`.

```
data.frame(a, b, e=findInterval(a, c(-Inf, 15, 20, 25, 30)))
```

Comment: Very nice use case of `cut`. A lot of better than my answer.

Comment: Thanks! It funny how often you encounter better ways of doing the simple stuff. Wouldn't suprised me if we get something nicer still.

Comment: Sorry. Just posted the same answer! Another option: `test$e = cut(test$a, breaks = c(0, 15, 20, 25, 30), labels = c(1, 2, 3, 4))`

Comment: The `findInterval` function may be a little simpler than `cut` for this case.

Answer (score 4):

I would use `cut()` for this:

```
test$e = cut(test$a, 
             breaks = c(0, 15, 20, 25, 30), 
             labels = c(1, 2, 3, 4))
```

If you want to "generalize" the cut--in other words, where you don't know exactly how many sets of 5  (levels) you need to make--you can take a two-step approach using `c()` and `seq()`:

```
test$e = cut(test$a, 
             breaks = c(0, seq(from = 15, to = max(test$a)+5, by = 5)))
levels(test$e) = 1:length(levels(test$e))
```

Since Backlin beat me to the `cut()` solution, here's another option (which I don't prefer in *this* case, but am posting just to demonstrate the many options available in R).

Use `recode()` from the `car` package.

```
require(car)    
test$e = recode(test$a, "0:15 = 1; 15:20 = 2; 20:25 = 3; 25:30 = 4")
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop.
You have nearly all you need:

```
test[test$a > 15 & test$a < 20, "e"] <- 2
```