# Re-factor a data frame after some values no longer exist

Tags: r

I am trying to re-factor across all column factors in a data frame to reduce the number of factor levels. Example is in my case, after I removed about 50% of rows in my data frame, a lot of columns have values in their factor levels that no longer exist, and I want to remove them. The data frame contains quite a lot of columns which are factors, so re-factoring them one at a time was getting tedious for me.

There's another question in SO called [refactor data.frame column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11950923/refactor-data-frame-column-values) but it doesn't address my question, so I thought I'll put in the question here as reference.

Comment: @henrik, you really need to get your r gold badge already  :)

Comment: Ah obviously I'm not good at searching for questions in SO :(

To the veterans: should I delete this redundant question?

Comment: No need to delete it. Duplicates serve exactly the purpose of making the issue better to search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some answers [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Refactor-all-factors-in-a-data-frame-td826749.html), and the one  I chose for my purpose was from Prof Brian Ripley:

```
ind <- sapply(DF, is.factor)
DF[ind] <- lapply(DF[ind], "[", drop=TRUE)
```

where the `DF` is the dataframe.

Comment: Have you tried `droplevels` or call `factor` again