# Make new factor columns based on different criterias in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to make various factor columns on my dataframe based on this column:
(real file is large, is not ordered and values have more decimals)

```
> df

0.05
0.1
0.15
0.20
0.25
0.30
.
.
.
0.90
0.95
0.99
```

The values range from 0.05 to 0.99 and I want to make a factor columns in 0.1 and 0.05 bins and possibly others as well. 
I tried using the `ifelse` function like this:

```
df$bin1 <- ifelse(df$V1 < 0.1, 1 , ifelse(0.1 <= df$V1 & df$V1 < 0.2,2,ifelse(...))
```

It worked but the command was large and very cumbersome for the other bins that I want to use.

Comment: The answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27902821/create-column-with-grouped-values-based-on-another-column-in-dplyr/27902907?noredirect=1#comment44206402_27902907) question should be helpful in learning how to use the `cut` function to group the data.

Comment: Or: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126326/how-to-quickly-form-groups-quartiles-deciles-etc-by-ordering-columns-in-a/4126475#4126475, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11950923/refactor-data-frame-column-values/11951058#11951058

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is with `hist()` function.

Like this:

```
hist((1:10), breaks=c(0, 2.5, 5.5, 12))
```

You can set your own breakpoints and it bins the results. If you want to do it without plotting, then something like this should work:

```
df$bin <- hist(df$V1, breaks=c(0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 1), plot = FALSE)
```